# How can I move a post from Meta Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, questions, migration, per-site-meta, winter-bash-2016

I already post some question on Meta Stack Overflow [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339810/which-post-exactly-is-my-father) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339820/how-can-i-get-the-whats-up-doc-hat), but I think this two question should be here on Meta Stack Exchange, because they are related to [winterbash-2016](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2016).

So how can I move a post from Meta Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Exchange, or this is not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually there is no need to migrate posts from one meta to another. See the meta sites as your town hall and the main meta as capitol hall. If you have your answers in your own town hall, why should it be brought up in the capitol hall?

Exceptional questions that have a greater use for the entire community can be migrated here by a moderator, but that usually isn't the case. Often questions aren't repeated that much and keeping it on the original meta gives the next user on your site their answer, instead of duplicating it there again.

If you do want to migrate it, you have to flag your post and request a moderator to move it. Keep in mind though that for the above reasons, a moderator may decline your request.

Answer (score 2):

You can't on your own, only a moderator can do that, and there's little reason for a moderator to do that. You already have answers there, and migrating them would just strip that Meta site of its answers and force users to go off to another site. Seems kind of pointless.

Comment: you are a moderator, did you find this two question should be migrate here or not?

Comment: I guess he doesn't judging his post. And animuson isn't just a moderator, he is a SO employee.

Comment: thank you @Patrick Hofman, i will wait his answer, maybe he can say some thing different :)